# Paint 10 cells of a 10x10 grid

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics

Can you paint 10 cells of a 10x10 grid such that the largest unpainted rectangle has area of 10 cells?

Here is a similar question for the 7x7 grid: [Paint 7 cells of a 7x7 grid](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/89507/paint-7-cells-of-a-7x7-grid)

Good luck!

Comment: I will delete my incorrect solution and retry

Comment: Ok I came up with a new solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I came up with:

> ```
> ..........
> .....x....
> ..x....x..
> ..........
> ....x.....
> .x......x.
> .....x....
> .......x..
> ..x...x...
> ..........
> ```

Method:

> 1. The edges should not be painted because anywhere you would paint an edge, you could do the same or better by painting one in from the edge instead.
>
>  2. Basically, I tried to leave areas of 3x3 and 2x5 and only "block" areas when they threatened to become 2x6 or 3x4.  It was a lot of trial and error.

Comment: I think you've done it this time - great work!

Answer (score 9):

It seems to be possible to do this with nine painted cells.

> [image]

Comment: Very nice. The solution seems to be unique (up to rotation).

Comment: Very nice indeed. I didn't know it was possible.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Confirmed.

Answer (score 5):

Using a computer I found there are quite a few solutions, so I decided to tighten the conditions a bit. If you also disallow unpainted rectangles of size $2\times5$ and $5\times2$, there seems to be only one solution left.

> ```
> . . . . . . . . . .
> . . . . X . . . X .
> . X . . . . . . . .
> . . . . . . X . . .
> . . . X . . . . . .
> . . . . . . . . X .
> . X . . . X . . . .
> . . . . . . . . . .
> . . . X . . . X . .
> . . . . . . . . . .
> ```

Comment: If you are interested you can try fitting n mines on n by n grids that are larger. I have results for that