# Prime magic star

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics, computer-puzzle, primes

Can you replace the letters with 10 consecutive primes such that the sum of numbers on each line is equal? I expect this to be solved with a computer.

Good luck!

[image]

Comment: Is there any method to solve this besides trial and error?

Comment: Yes there are certain properties about consecutive primes that help you reduce the search space.

Comment: For the record can you please stop criticizing every puzzle I post. Yes I like mathematical puzzles and some of them require a bit of trial and error. I don't see anything wrong with that. Also I think it is ok to solve puzzles with a computer. In fact there are some very clever algorithms that allow you to reduce the search space and find the solution faster. For me coding/developing such algorithms is part of the fun, especially if you can use them to solve larger cases and push the boundaries of your knowledge.

Comment: I like mathematical puzzles too. But for something to be a *puzzle*, it should permit a clever "aha moment" that leads to the solution. What makes a good puzzle is a "path" to the solution, somehow "built into" the puzzle. Questions that require large amounts of trial and error don't satisfy that, in my view.

Comment: Your ["Paint 7 cells of a 7x7 grid"](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/89507/paint-7-cells-of-a-7x7-grid) had a very nice path to the solution (though I don't know whether it was intended). But I'm critical of this (and similar puzzles) because I don't think it has an "aha moment", or a natural "path" to the solution. If the intended way to solve something is brute-force search (or *mostly* brute-force search), I don't think it's very good as a puzzle. It may be a great programming challenge for a site such as Project Euler, but that does not make it a puzzle.

Comment: I agree with @Deusovi on this one, as manually solving it is practically impossible. If you intended for this to be solved with a computer, you should say so and present it as a coding challenge. As it is, one might expect to find a solution in small primes. Woe unto them.

Comment: Is the solution unique?

Comment: @JMP that sounds like a very hard question.

Comment: @JMP there is at least one solution, not sure that it is unique.

Comment: @JMP excluding rotations and reflections, there are 12 distinct solutions. I have not examined them closely, but I expect they are related in some other way. I also expect that there are other solutions with larger primes.

Comment: Nice work Daniel. Feel free to post your solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, this image shows examples of translation that preserves the summed groups. As mentioned in comment, there are $12$ equivalent arrangements in this class.

[image: translation]

Here is a solution set:

> A=13907
>  B=13913
>  C=13997
>  D=13999
>  E=13921
>  F=13933
>  G=13963
>  H=14009
>  I=13931
>  J=13967

There are seven other solution sets with primes less than 100,000 and countless more with larger primes.

Comment: You got it! The first answer had a bug, but this one is correct. Feel free to post other solution sets.